# Error when passing array to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very new to C++ and am writing a program that is SUPPOSED to do the following:

1. fill up an array of integers based on a user-defined constant.
2. pass the array in step # 1 to a function that computes the mean of the integers in the array.
3. pass the array in step # 2 to a function that computes the standard deviation of the integers in the array.

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 100;
int custArray[];

void fillArray(int SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
double standardDeviation(double[], int);
double mean(double[], int);
double arithmeticAverage;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i;
    fillArray(SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The mean is: " << mean(custArray[], i);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The standard deviation is: " << standardDeviation(custArray[], i);

    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    int i = 0;
    custArray[0] = { 1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
     custArray[i] = i + 1;

    return;
}

double mean(double custArray[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    double sumOfElements = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    {
    sumOfElements += custArray[i];
    }
    arithmeticAverage = sumOfElements / i;
    return (arithmeticAverage);
 }

double standardDeviation(double custArray[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    double standardDeviation;
    double tempSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    {
    tempSum += pow((custArray[i] - arithmeticAverage), 2);
    }
    standardDeviation = sqrt(tempSum / (SIZE_OF_ARRAY));
    return (standardDeviation);
}
```

I'm getting an error in the following lines of code:

```
cout << "The mean is: " << mean(custArray[], i);
```

and

```
cout << "The standard deviation is: " << standardDeviation(custArray[], i);
```

that reads:  "syntax error: ']'

Why?

Comment: You should have `int custArray[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];` to declare `custArray` with a size of `SIZE_OF_ARRAY`.

Comment: `standardDeviation(custArray[], i);` should simply be `standardDeviation(custArray, i);`, same for `mean(custArray, i);`, and finally as @crashmstr said: `int custArray[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];`. Please check your books about the syntax basics again.

Comment: **Note** that fixing _your_ basic syntax errors isn't the main purpose of this site. It's meant to provide (at best) canonical questions and answers, that are really suitable to help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of problems in your program. However, I did fix them and it compiles without errors.

- **First of all**, you dont pass arrays into a functuin with the `[]` after its name; you just type the variable name.
- **Second**, your `mean()` and `standardDeviation()` functions both had your array declared as a `double`.
- **Third**, you passed the variable `i` from your `main()` which was not initialized. I think you meant to pass `SIZE_OF_ARRAY`.
- **Fourth**, you need only create the main function like this: `int main()`. Your original program had `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` which is a Microsoft specific standard.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE_OF_ARRAY = 100;
int custArray[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];

void fillArray(int SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
double standardDeviation(int[], int);
double mean(int[], int);
double arithmeticAverage;

int main()
{

    //int i; no need for this

    fillArray(SIZE_OF_ARRAY);

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The mean is: " << mean(custArray, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The standard deviation is: " << standardDeviation(custArray, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);

    return 0;
}


void fillArray(int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    int i = 0;

    custArray[0] = { 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
         custArray[i] = i + 1;

    return;
}

double mean(int custArray[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    double sumOfElements = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    {
        sumOfElements += custArray[i];
    }
    arithmeticAverage = sumOfElements / i;
    return (arithmeticAverage);
 }

double standardDeviation(int custArray[], int SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
{
    double standardDeviation;
    double tempSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    {
        tempSum += pow((custArray[i] - arithmeticAverage), 2);
    }
    standardDeviation = sqrt(tempSum / (SIZE_OF_ARRAY));
    return (standardDeviation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris.  I fixed up the syntax errors and the code now compiles.  And, I'm getting expected results!  -Elizabeth

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the brackets in the function call argument. Just remove them like:

```
mean(custArray, i)
```

Comment: I've amended the code to include the above-mentioned suggestions and am getting this error:  'double mean(double [],int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [100]' to 'double []'.  Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: @user3654700 I think that error should be pretty obvious. An array of integers is not the same as an array of doubles.